# Paramater concat inline

Tags: azure-logic-apps, string-concatenation

In my Logic App, i have 2 parameters username and tenant. I need to concat these 2 with an '@' in the middle. I tried to concat it using below tries and none worked.

```
@{concat([parameters('username')],'@',[parameters('tenant')])}
@{concat([parameters('username')],''@'',[parameters('tenant')])}
@{concat(parameters('username'),'@',parameters('tenant'))}
```

Finally i had to create 3 seperate variables to hold each value and concat it and that worked.

```
@{concat(variables('username'),variables('at'),variables('tenant'))}
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Here is the app

[image]

Here is the parameters for app, username and password is fetched from params file

[image]

Here is the error when run

[image]

Comment: Hi, I used `@{concat(parameters('username'),'@',parameters('tenant'))}` and it worked. The workflow of azure logic app is designed like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xhT6.png), and the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reApH.png) seems no problem. I don't know why yours didn't work, I look forward to your more information.

Comment: @FrankGong just to be clear i use it in the "body" of the Http action, like "body": "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns... <wsse:Username>@{concat(parameters('username'),'@',parameters('tenant'))}</wsse:Username>.... When i tried to run like you suggested i get the error as 'The workflow parameter 'username' is not found.'.

Comment: Hi, I created two parameters by this [way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6MTi.png) to test it, this may be the reason you can't find the `username` parameter. I created a `HTTP` action, it still worked. Could you please give me a `Azure logic app` workflow screenshot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg6ne.png) to help me reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FrankGong added the screenshots

Comment: I see that in the screenshot you provided, the HTTP action uses `username`, why does your error message show `xxx-username is not found`?

Comment: @FrankGong The error picture i have added is from the actual app run. For now, i have used variables that are initialized with parameters.